# Question on checking character type on Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on my homework and the first line code is provided and cannot be changed. I am able to run in PyCharm but not able to run in Hackerrank to submit my homework.

I have tried to find what's wrong with my code but I think the problem is related to input. I think teacher wants us to use input as variable?

```py
def check_character_type(input):
    # Write your code
    ch = input
    if ch[0].isalpha():
        print("alphabet")
    elif ch[0].isdigit():
        print("digit")
    else:
        print("special")
    return ch

check_character_type(input)
```

When I run the code in Hackerrank, error message are

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 29, in <module>
    check_character_type(input)
  File "Solution.py", line 21, in check_character_type
    if ch[0].isalpha():
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: input is a built-in function..don't use that as a variable name...what does your input variable look like

Comment: my teacher told me to get the input from function parameter, not from input function.
so I dun know how to deal with this...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue here is you have named the parameter to your function `input`, which is a reserved function provided by Python used to read input from the `STDIN`. You then alias this to `ch` and attempt to subscript it, effectively trying to access an index of a function (which you can't).

The solution would be to change your parameter name from `input` to something like `in` or `s` instead, something that isn't a reserved keyword.

Comment: Thank you but I just asked my teacher and he said he wants to use input as parameter. I am so struggling on this. He told me to return "digit", "alphabet" and "special" instead or print

Comment: Ah ok, in that case change your last line to `check_character_type(input())`. Do let me know if that works!

Comment: As for the returning bit, you might want to change your `print()` statements to `return` instead, so for example you would do `return "alphabet"` instead of `print("alphabet")`

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Python and programming and I ask a lot of stupid question.
so the question is ( if the input is a string instead of one character, take the first character of the string )

here is my code so far
```python
def check_character_type(input):
    # Write your code
    ch = input
    if ch[0].isalpha():
        return "alpabet"
    elif ch[0].isdigit():
        return "digit"
    else:
        return "special"

check_character_type(input())
```

the error is EOFError: EOF when reading a line 
and there is no output in the test file :((( T.T

Comment: I see, so Hackerrank does seem to expect a print. In that case, make your last line into `typ = check_character_type(input())` and add a line below it saying `print(typ)`. Also would it be possible to include a link to the Hackerrank question?

Comment: When I make my last line into your suggestion, I could run the programme perfectly in Pycharm. But when it comes to Hackerrank, error message:
```python
input = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```
also, there is no output in Hackerrank
I am in a introduction course on python so I think the solution should be quite straight forward. 
thank you very much. I tried many time and so struggle

Comment: No worries, could you include a link to the HackerRank question you are attempting so I could take a look at the specifications?

Comment: Thank you .
 the link is https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/9fi3b67soo2/f5aeb7828d647fac9ae0cf193fb6601f

Comment: I do not have the authorisation to take a look at the question. Could you paste your code into pastebin.com and link it here instead? It would make it easier to look for bugs.

Comment: sure here it is https://pastebin.com/tFgh4hBU
or if it doesnt work finally I could give you my access to Hackerrank thank you so much

Comment: Ok, could you try commenting out the last 2 lines and running it? (The line with `typ = check_character_type(input())` and `print(typ)`? So that way the code doesn't print anything.

Comment: Ohh I just remove the last line of the programme and it finally works.  You help me a lot .

Thank you very much~~~

Comment: All of this and the working solution is in my answer

Answer (score 0):

your issue as mentioned in the last answer and comments it that you are using the function named input as the name of your variable...try it like this:

```
inp = 'test'

def check_character_type(inp):
    # Write your code
    ch = inp
    if ch[0].isalpha():
        print("alphabet")
    elif ch[0].isdigit():
        print("digit")
    else:
        print("special")
    return ch

check_character_type(inp)
```

output:

```
alphabet
'test'
```

if by "I think teacher wants us to use input as variable" you mean that you're supposed to provide input before hand, then do this first:

```
inp = input('Enter the input')
```